# Create a list of all messages, warnings, and errors returned by a function

Tags: r, error-handling, suppress-warnings

I have a function in R that calls other functions. Occasionally, those functions can return the same message. I only want the message to print once. What is the best way to handle that?

In the example below, `functionC` will print "The value is 5." two times if the argument for b and c is 5. I only want it to print once.

```
functionA <- function(a){
  
  if(a==5){
    message("The value is 5.")
  }
  return(a-2)
}

functionB <- function(b){
  
  if(b==5){
    message("The value is 5.")
  }
  return(b+7)
}

functionC <- function(a,b){
  a <- functionA(a)
  b <- functionB(b)
  c <- rbind(a,b)
  return(c)
}

functionC(5,5)
```

Comment: I think I'd just write the functions differently. Unless this is just an example and you have a better real-world case?

Comment: `functionA` and `functionB` can be called separately by the user, but I also want to give them the option to call the two functions together in `functionC`. If they are called separately, I still want them to be able to see the message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `withCallingHandlers` to catch (and suppress) the messages in real time, then use `unique` to reduce them, then re-`message` them out. I'll add a `(n times)` when repeated for the sake of transparency (since otherwise you may have no clear idea how noisy inner-calls are).

```r
functionC <- function(a,b){
  msgs <- character(0)
  a <- withCallingHandlers(
    functionA(a),
    message = function(m) {
      msgs <<- c(msgs, conditionMessage(m))
      invokeRestart("muffleMessage")
    })
  b <- withCallingHandlers(
    functionB(b),
    message = function(m) {
      msgs <<- c(msgs, conditionMessage(m))
      invokeRestart("muffleMessage")
    })
  msgs <- trimws(msgs)
  # since 'table' does not preserve the original order, we'll do a few
  # extra steps to ensure the messages appear in the order of their
  # _first_ appearance
  counts <- table(msgs)
  counts <- counts[match(names(counts), msgs)]
  msgs <- paste0(names(counts), ifelse(counts > 1, sprintf(" (%d times)", counts), ""))
  for (m in msgs) message(m)
  c <- rbind(a, b)
  return(c)
}
functionC(5,5)
# The value is 5. (2 times)
#   [,1]
# a    3
# b   12
```

You can repeat the `message=`/`"muffleMessage"` with `warning=`/`"muffleWarning"` to catch warnings as well ... though you might as well use `purrr::quietly` for that:

```r
functionC2 <- function(a,b){
  msgs <- character(0)
  warns <- character(0)
  aout <- purrr::quietly(functionA)(a)
  bout <- purrr::quietly(functionB)(b)
  fewer <- function(z) {
    z <- trimws(z)
    counts <- table(z)
    counts <- counts[match(names(counts), z)]
    paste0(names(counts), ifelse(counts > 1, sprintf(" (%d times)", counts), ""))
  }
  msgs <- fewer(c(aout$messages, bout$messages))
  warns <- fewer(c(aout$warnings, bout$warnings))
  cout <- rbind(aout$result, bout$result)
  for (m in msgs) message(m)
  for (w in warns) warning(w)
  return(cout)
}
```

Comment: @missgwolf, see my edit for another clean way to catch all in fewer lines of code.

Comment: excellent addition @r2evans, tysm!

Answer (score 1):

Would suppressing the functionA/functionB warnings and including a new 'a and/or b is 5' warning suit your use-case? E.g.

```r
functionA <- function(a){
  if(a==5){
    message("The value is 5.")
  }
  return(a-2)
}

functionB <- function(b){
  if(b==5){
    message("The value is 5.")
  }
  return(b+7)
}

functionC <- function(a,b){
  a <- functionA(a)
  b <- functionB(b)
  c <- rbind(a,b)
  return(c)
}
functionC(5,5)
#> The value is 5.
#> The value is 5.
#>   [,1]
#> a    3
#> b   12

functionD <- function(a,b){
  if(a==5 | b==5){
    message("The value of a and/or b is 5.")
  }
  a <- suppressMessages(functionA(a))
  b <- suppressMessages(functionB(b))
  c <- rbind(a,b)
  return(c)
}
functionD(5,5)
#> The value of a and/or b is 5.
#>   [,1]
#> a    3
#> b   12
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This works well for this simple reprex, but my function is more complex. I'm hoping to capture all messages/warnings in a dataframe or list, and then just choose which ones to display.

Comment: No problem, I thought that might be the case. Glad you solved it using r2evans approach :)